# DynamoDB Unique list of elements across all records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table that stores list of names for a particular record. I want to ensure that a name can never be used for any other record more than once. The names column should also not be empty; there should always be at least 1 given name.

```
|          ID           |          Names                                 |
|-----------------------|------------------------------------------------|
|          111          |          [john, bob]                           |
|          222          |          [tim]                                 |
|          333          |          [bob] (invalid bob already used)      |
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I believe for this case is to simply use a 2nd table for the values you are interested in being the primary key. Then in application code, simply check that new table if they exist or not to determine if you should create a new record in the primary table. For a List[L] this simply avoids having to traverse every single list of every record to determine if a particular scalar value already exists or not. Credit to Tamas.

[image]

https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-properly-implement-unique-constraints-in-dynamodb/

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a blog post describing how to best enforce uniqueness constraints: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/

Comment: That example is only for scalar values not list of items. Also its such a terrible design strategy. You are filling up your table with useless records overtime that you now need to keep track of instead of dynamodb just being able to support unique keys/indexes

Comment: @turbofood this is a very popular strategy when using DynamoDB. For your case you will need to insert an item for each name in the list. The table may get filled with 1 million items, but that may be under 50MB of data. The design of DynamoDB means that even with 100 million items, it will not impact performance and will cost under $1 a month to store these values. If you do not want to manage unique items yourselves, there are libraries such as OneTable which can offload some of this work, depending on your use case.

Comment: @RossWilliams So I would insert records such as `name#bob` into the id column & that would create a unique constraint which prevents any List [L] from having that value ? Even though name attribute is a List [L] & not a scalar ?

Comment: It is a two step process, so use a transaction. In the transaction use a `Put` to insert `unique#name#bob`, `unique#name#alice`, etc, but add a `ConditionExpression` = `attribute_not_exists(#id)`, and `ExpressionAttributeNames` = {'#id': 'id'} for each item. Also include a `Put` for your original item. If any `Put` fails in the transaction, you know that item is already used and the transaction does not commit. If the list can have more than 24 names, you must do a series of TransactWrites and handle rollbacks yourself.

Comment: Why 24 names must I use a TransactWrites & handle rollbacks myself? It could have more than 24 names so, im thinking a 2nd table is just far more easier & safe. Plus in DynamoDB you cant even specify size constraints so I wouldn't want to have check the length of the list everytime im looking to insert a record to determine if I should execute this whole new separate flow.

Comment: TransactWrite is limited to 25 operations. 1 operation is to insert your item, so you have 24 left to check the list unique constraints. To be clear, the list is the names inside the new item you want to insert, not the total list of names already in the database. I'm not sure what you are looking to gain by using a second table. Nothing you have said indicates a second table will solve this issue, you still need to add each `name` as its own item.

Comment: @RossWilliams By not trying to store everything under the same table, I don't have to handle individual transactions as you are describing; or in multiple flows. Its a simple `Query` lookup by the name attribute as the new primary key of your second table & I will automatically know whether it exists or not. I don't have to see if the transaction failed & then, assume its because of the implied unique constraint or do any special exception handling

Comment: And when the insert to one table succeeds and the other fails, then what? Or when one write returns a network error response and you’re not sure if it was written before or after the network glitch, then what? Handling these cases is what transactions provides.